# Random Color for each row in a list view from array of colors

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am setting the background color  for each row in my customadapter as

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {





    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupon_list_row, null);
        int temp_index = ExtraFu.randInt(0, 9);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[temp_index]);
        Log.d("temp_index", String.valueOf(temp_index));
    }
```

My array of color

```
int color_arr[]={R.color.cred,R.color.cpink,R.color.cpurple,R.color.cdpurple,R.color.cindigo,R.color.cblue,R.color.cdorange,R.color.cgreen,R.color.cbroun,R.color.ccyan};
```

this is the function randInt

```
  public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

the row background is set to two color. Is that the random number is generated same all the time?

Comment: compare position number and color array in if condition. with in the loop set background color to convertview.

Comment: I cant do that because the list is dynamic and can contain n number of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  if (position%4 == 0){
             // set convertView Background          
        } else if (position%4 == 1){
            // set convertView Background  
        } else if (position%4 == 2){
            // set convertView Background  
        } else if (position%4 == 3){
            // set convertView Background  
        }
```

This will randomly generate the four different color in your listview.

inside adapter

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = lv.inflate(res, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position%4 == 0){
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1e86cf"));
        } else if (position%4 == 1){
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2ca0ea"));
        } else if (position%4 == 2){
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2cc4ea"));
        } else if (position%4 == 3){
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2ceae3"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

ViewHolder Class:

```
    class ViewHolder{
        public TextView textView;
    }
```

adapter custom layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So if i have n number of item ? and whats wrong with that random number?

Comment: in my answer it will repeat the four color. randomly it may change.

Comment: I have done the same thing what you have written. but instead of 4 I use 10 but stil am getting only two different color

Comment: u may did any mistake check your code. this code is worked well in my app.

Comment: try step by step initially try it for 4 and 6 then move to 10.

Comment: Wait let me post it. Please have a look at
int color_arr[]={R.color.cred,R.color.cpink,R.color.cpurple,R.color.cdpurple,R.color.cindigo,R.color.cblue,R.color.cdorange,R.color.cgreen,R.color.cbroun,R.color.ccyan};
        if (position%10 == 0){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[1]);
        }

Comment: instead of giving background to your convertview give background to R.layout.coupon_list_row items with the help of ViewHolder.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: its 404 page not foud

Answer (score 3):

**I have edited your code**

**you need to use below line i have checked its working finr for my layout**

```
 convertView.setBackgroundResource(color_arr[rnd]);
```

**Your updated code not checked on my side**

```
if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupon_list_row, null);



 int color_arr[]=  {R.color.cred,R.color.cpink,R.color.cpurple,R.color.cdpurple,R.color.cindigo,R.color.cblue,R.color.cdorange,R.color.cgreen,R.color.cbroun,R.color.ccyan};
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(color_arr.length);


        //convertView.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[temp_index]);

        convertView.setBackgroundResource(color_arr[rnd]);

    }
```

**Reference Code is which i have tried and works fine so do the needful changes**

```
int color_arr[] = {R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark};


    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(color_arr.length);

    linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(color_arr[rnd]);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Random Color Generation :

```
private int getRandomColor() {
  SecureRandom rgen = new SecureRandom();
  return Color.HSVToColor(150, new float[]{
      rgen.nextInt(359), 1, 1
  });
}
```

And set `BackGroundColor` of  each item after retrieving the item position:

```
holder.textView.setBackGroundColor(getRandomColor());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below code to get Random colors**

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: This is generating only 2 colors.

Comment: no this code will generate all the colors randomly not only two colors. but randomly so that it will repeat colors randomly. you can check it again. if you don't have any restriction of colors then you can use above code.

Answer (score 0):

Tips: Use modulo operator, to Color each row with 4 colors

```js
export const moduloColor = (rowIndex: number): string => {
let rep
    if (rowIndex % 4 === 0) { // if rowIndex is a multiple of 4
        rep = '#00838F'
    } else if (rowIndex % 3 === 0) { // if rowIndex is a multiple of 3
        rep = '#00ACC1'
    } else if (rowIndex % 2 === 0) { // if rowIndex is a multiple of 2
        rep = '#26C6DA'
    } else {
        rep = '#80DEEA'
    }
return rep
}
```

[modulo](/questions/tagged/modulo)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)